Image not changing dynamically
I am working on status tracking view. I have some Int values based on that my progress should change currently I'm facing 2 issues., How can I bring this same UI view without changing the enum to an array and Image is not changing dynamically based upon the status. OrderStatus should not be an array.
How can I simply this more? what am I missing here?
public enum OrderStatus: Int {
    case some1 = 10
    case some2 = 20
    case some3 = 30
    case some4 = 40
    case some5 = 50
    case some6 = 60
    case some7 = 99
    
    var text: String {
        switch self {
        case .some3:
            return ""
        case .some4:
            return ""
        case .some5:
            return ""
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }
    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .some3:
            return ""
        case .some4:
            return ""
        case .some5:
            return ""
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }
    var statusIcon: String {
        isCompleted() ? Icon.badgeConditionComplete : Icon.badgeConditionIncomplete
    }
    
    func isCompleted() -> Bool {
        switch self {
        case .some3, .some4, .some5:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}


struct StatusTrackingView: View {
    
    let steps: [OrderStatus]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 4) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(steps.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    let step = steps[index]
                    let isCompleted = step.isCompleted()
                    Image(step.statusIcon)
                    
                    if index < steps.count - 1 {
                        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color.Gray.light)
                                .frame(width: progressBarWidth, height: 4)
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color.Primary.base)
                                .frame(width: filledProgressBarWidth(index: index), height: 4)
                                .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: step == steps.last ? 100 : 0))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            HStack {
                ForEach(steps.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    VStack {
                        Text(steps[index].text)
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.Ink.base)
                            .font(Font.SFPro.textRegular(size: 10))
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                            .frame(width: (index == steps.startIndex || index == steps.endIndex - 1) ? 46.5 : 2 * (progressBarWidth - (46.5 / 2)) )
                    }
                    .frame(width: (index == steps.startIndex || index == steps.endIndex - 1) ? (currentScreenWidth - progressBarWidth) / 2 : 1.3 * (progressBarWidth - (46.5 / 2)) )
                    .padding(.leading, index == steps.startIndex ? (46.5 / 2) : 0)
                    .padding(.trailing, index == steps.endIndex - 1 ? (46.5 / 2) : 0)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: currentScreenWidth)
        }
    }
    
    var progressBarWidth: CGFloat {
        let totalWidth = currentScreenWidth - 107 - CGFloat(steps.count) * 24
        return totalWidth / CGFloat(steps.count - 1)
    }
    
    private func filledProgressBarWidth(index: Int) -> CGFloat {
        let stepProgress = stepProgress(index: index)
        return progressBarWidth * stepProgress
    }
    
    private func stepProgress(index: Int) -> CGFloat {
        let completedIndex = steps.firstIndex { $0.isCompleted() } ?? 0
        if index < completedIndex {
            return 1.0
        } else if index == completedIndex {
            return 0.6
        } else {
            return 0.0
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    StatusTrackingView(steps: [.some3, .some4, .some5])
}



Please show a [mre] - something I can directly copy and paste into a new project and reproduce the problem.

I don’t understand the question but you should stop using indices in your ForEach loops, loop over the objects directly instead, ForEach(steps, id: \.self) { step in … }

Note as mentioned, do not use ForEach(steps.indices, id: \.self) etc... this is considered
bad programming. Restructure your code.
In your parent view try declaring something like
@State private var steps: [OrderStatus] = [.some1, .some2, ...] and in your StatusTrackingView
have @Binding var steps: [OrderStatus]. So when in your parent view
you add or remove a OrderStatus to steps your StatusTrackingView will update.
